# Find packed size of a structure

Tags: c, gcc, sizeof, packed

Is there a way to find the packed size of a structure defined and declared without packed attribute in GCC compiler?

Example:

```
struct Name
{
   int a;
   char ch;
}
```

any function or macro like `get_packed_size(Name)` should return 5

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: No it shouldn't return 5. The size includes alignment and [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Structure_padding). It should return 8 on most platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way... you only have `sizeof()`, and you need to take care of the padding...

Comment: Obligatory: `sizeof` is not a function. :)

Answer (score 2):

Define your struct using a macro that provides the required information. For example (though there are other possible implementations):

```
#define DEFINE_STRUCT_WITH_KNOWN_PACKED_SIZE(StructName, StructBody)\
struct StructName StructBody\
struct __attribute__ ((__packed__)) StructName##_packed StructBody

#define GET_PACKED_SIZE(StructName) sizeof (struct StructName##_packed)

DEFINE_STRUCT_WITH_KNOWN_PACKED_SIZE(Name, {
   int a;
   char ch;
};)

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%lu", GET_PACKED_SIZE(Name));
}
```